# vs.net 2010 tfs checking in

Tags: visual-studio-2010

a few questions about vs.net 2010 tfs in a multi developer environment:
1. should it be checking in code first and then 'get latest' or vice versa in order not to break the build?
2. is it possible to checkin just one file without breaking the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the latest version before checking in and merging changes from TFS with your edits. If you would just check in your changes the files on TFS would get replaced with your versions, removing any changes commited by others.

Comment: so it is not asking to merge stuff when you checkin first?

Comment: what about checkin in just one file would it break the build?

Comment: The thing is that you could merge your changes in without getting latest first, but how are you going to be sure that what you checked in actually compiles? Checking in one file is possible, why should it not be?

Comment: What if you checked out a solution or projectfile and then checkin another file will it break the build?

Comment: That depends on the types of changes you're checking in, right? If you get the latest version before checking in and check that everything works before check in, the code in TFS works, obviously.